# Laravel .map not found

Tags: laravel

I removed the selectpicker from my laravel application. I have still this error message on:

[image]

What i have to do to remove this error message? I have also other .map files not found, but not used also.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually related to Laravel it is more related to CSS.
these are source maps you can disbale these from dev-tools Or

- Delete /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */ in
  css/bootstrap.min.css
- delete /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */ in css/bootstrap.css

Hope this helps.